# Reading last modified file name from Amazon S3 bucket in GO

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I need to read the filenames in an amazon s3 bucket using Golang.
The bucket contains csv files mainly with 2 types of name formats.

```
1. uploaded/2022-03-21-18:31:06.608058.csv
2. overwritten/2022-03-22-18:31:06.608058.csv
```

I need to find out the name of the last modified file with **uploaded** prefix. (The bucket in question contains 1000s of files.)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to list the files, parse the name (or check the last modified timestamp of it).

Comment: If you can confindently assert the year, month, day, hour , minute, etc of the most recent objects, use that for the Prefix to ListObjectsV2.  Otherwise you have no choice but to list everything and do a comperison yourself

Comment: The timestamp in the object key may present the creation date or something else. It seems the OP is looking for the last modified object. @Daffodil can you clarify?

Comment: @reda la The timestamp in the object key is the creation date and time. I am happy if I can get  the filename based on the last modified date or the timestamp in the object key. Effectively both of these should be the same as my application never tries to modify a file post its creation.

Comment: @Daffodil, my second code example can help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments:

You have to list all keys started with the given prefix, then (in your code) sort and find the wanted object key.

```golang
    ...

    objs := []types.Object{}
    params := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket:     aws.String(s.bucket),
        Prefix:     aws.String(prefix), //uploaded
    }
    p := s3.NewListObjectsV2Paginator(svc, params)

    for p.HasMorePages() {
        out, err := p.NextPage(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        objs = append(objs, out.Contents...)
    }

    if l :=len(objs); l > 0 {
        sort.Slice(objs, func(a, b int) bool {
            return objs[a].LastModified.Before(*objs[b].LastModified)
        })

        return objs[l-1].Key, nil
    }

    return "", nil
```

If you are trying to find the object key with the most recent DateTime (within the key's name), then you can use the **StartAfter** parameter to avoid listing all available keys.

```golang
    ...

    lastModifiedKey := ""

    params := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket:     aws.String(s.bucket),
        Prefix:     aws.String(prefix), //uploaded
        StartAfter: aws.String(previousSearchKey),
    }
    p := s3.NewListObjectsV2Paginator(svc, params)

    for p.HasMorePages() {
        out, err := p.NextPage(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        // ListObjectV2 sorts key by ascending order & your name format is sortable
        lastModifiedKey =  out.Contents[len(out.Contents) -1]
    }

    return lastModifiedKey, nil
```

Note that **StartAfter** key doesn't require to be an existing key in the bucket.

It may be the result of a previous search, or a guessed value that you can assert is behind (and preferably close to the wanted result).